# Links stroke-width in threshold function for D3.js force-layout network

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am currently using the D3 library for my network visualisation, and more precisely the force layout.

I’m using the function provided by Simon Raper here:

http://jsfiddle.net/simonraper/TdHgx/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=TdHgx

to apply a dynamic threshold on my network.

However I noticed a problem, the stroke-width of the network is incorrectly display when the threshold change. Even on Mr Raper example you can see that the stroke-width of the links change for no reason.

A quick look at the console showed me that the values are correct and the shape of the network is correct as well, only the display of the stroke-width of the links are wrong. And it seems to be an indexing problem as the incorrect values are not random but correspond to other links.

The best I could find was to replace:

```
link=link.data(graph.links);
```

by

```
link = link.data(force.links(), function(d){return d.source.name + "-" + d.target.name; });
```

in the restart function.

The stroke-width of the links is now correct but when doing this the links would sometimes not be visible…

If anyone more experienced with the D3 library could help I would greatly appreciate ;)

Answer (score 1):

It should have been:

```
link.data(force.links(), function(d){return d.source + "-" + d.target; });
```

there is no `d.source.name` or `d.target.name`

working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/1k1dLrt3/)

**EDIT**

On sliding the threshold.
There is a filtering of nodes happening, that is the reason for links nots showing up.

```
function threshold(thresh) {
    //clearing up links
    graph.links.splice(0, graph.links.length);
    //only selecting and pushing links with value > threshold.
        for (var i = 0; i < graphRec.links.length; i++) {
            if (graphRec.links[i].value > thresh) {graph.links.push(graphRec.links[i]);}
        }
    restart();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but your code doesn't work. 90% of the links disappear after you move the threshold above 2. Also you have : link = link.data(graph.links, function(d){return d.source + "-" + d.target; }); instead of link.data(force.links(), function(d){return d.source + "-" + d.target; });

Comment: Check my edit section above...that will explain why the links go away on sliding.

Comment: I already know how it works :), but if you look closely to your network you'll noticed that some nodes are connected but the links are not visible. By looking at how the nodes moves you can quickly see that they should be connected but the link is not display. When the threshold is 4-5 for example you can see some nodes staying grouped together in the center but their links are not visible, and I already checked their values, they should be connected. Edit: Try to move them around you'll see what I mean, they are connected.

Comment: I think this solves the problem http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/1k1dLrt3/2/  the selection is not correct in the restart block. So the restart function should have ` link = svg.selectAll(".link"); node = svg.selectAll(".node");` please let me know if this what you intent i ll update my answer. Thanks :)

Comment: Now all the links are display, but their stroke-width is incorrect. Same problem as the one here: http://jsfiddle.net/simonraper/TdHgx/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=TdHgx The stroke-width change between two nodes when you change the threshold, but it shouldn't as the connection values never change. This is the real problem I had originally.